# Can't get element ID (just in a specific table) - returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get an element ID, like `<tr>` or `<td>` and when I call `$('element').id;` or `$('element').attr('id');` i get undefined :(

Am I doing something wrong?

### Someone answered and deleted:

I can change to:

```
$(this).closest('tbody > tr').attr('id')
```

And it will work!

**THANKS!!!!!!**

The table is PHP-genereated.

Snippet (attention to `<tr id=\"". $info['id'] ."\">`, this is what I want):

```
<!--  TAB 3 (READ) -->
<div id="read" class="span9">
    <div id="deleteForm"></div>
    <table id="db_table" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th class="width_adjust">Pre&ccedilo</th>
            <th>Ingredientes</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cardapio")
            or die(mysql_error());

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
            $info['preco'] = str_replace('.', ',', $info['preco']);
            print("

                 <tr id=\"". $info['id'] ."\">
                    <td>".$info['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$info['nome']."</td>
                    <td>R$ ".$info['preco']."</td>
                    <td>".$info['descricao']."</td>
                    <td><a class=\"deleteRow\" href=\"/cadastro.php?id=". $info['id'] ."\"><button class=\"close\">&times;</button></td>
                </tr>

            "); } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to, when the user clicks on an `<a>` element, it pop-ups a confirm dialog and if OK is clicked, it deletes the desired row from DB/html.

What I'm trying to do (javaScript):

```
// Delete row in READ tab
    $('a.deleteRow').click(function(e) {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (x==true){
            //Ajax for delete entry from DB
            var id_var = $(this).closest('tr').id;
            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers
            else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // for IE

            var url = '/components/delete.php?id_var=' + id_var;
            xhr.open('GET', url, false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                    var div = document.getElementById('deleteForm');
                    div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
            //FadeOut to delete from HTML
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }else{
            //e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
        }
    });
```

Example image (testing with `table` element):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgWU3.png

Rendered HTML:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFcFP.png
http:// pastebin.com/hZLxRL0V

Comment: Show is your actual JavaScript where you are trying to do this

Comment: what is element. is it a dom object or class or id

Comment: Please show the browser rendered HTML & jquery code. Copy and paste the view source :)

Comment: why do you want to get an id of an element exactyl? ```$("table").attr("id")``` works only reliably if there is only one table on the page

Comment: Edited. Sorry don't give me -1 :(

Comment: On that table element... shouldn't it be $('table')[0].id?

Comment: Ops! Why is this [0] index needed? But what I want is the <tr id=...> element... It was just an example!

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').prop('id')` should just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
var id_var = $(this).closest('tr').id;
```

Is almost there, but you want the identifier of the first element in the jQuery result set, not the `.id` property of the result set itself (which is undefined):

```
var id_var = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nc4j8/

```
<table id='table'>
    <tr data-id='1'>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td><a class='deleteRow'>delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id='2'>
        <td>Cześć</td>
        <td><a class='deleteRow'>delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id='3'>
        <td>Good morning</td>
        <td><a class='deleteRow'>delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$('#table').on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
    var $tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    var id = $tr.attr('data-id');
    $tr.fadeOut('fast');
});
```